# Collaboration development mixing public and private repositories

Tags: git, continuous-integration, repository, collaboration, synchronization

There is a project our team would like to collaborate with another company on. The current code base is stored in our Git (Bitbucket) repo with a CI pipeline configured to build using our infrastructure. (Jenkins, K8s, Argo CD) One wants to collaborate with another company without having to procure additional licenses for them or/and let them into our user base. One wants to keep the CI build pipeline inside. Some sort of public repo with synchronisation possibility with our internal Git.

Comment: In the tools you mention, which ones have a per user license ? Bitbucket for sure, but Jenkins ? K8s ? Argo CD ?

Comment: BitBucket. We have a commercial version of Jenkins, however BB is the key issue here.